# Dirac delta function properties

Tags: dirac-delta

Good afternoon!
I can't prove 
$$x \cdot \delta^m(x)=-m\delta^{(m-1)}(x), m=1,2,3....$$
I have found that
$\int x \cdot \delta'(x)dx =x \cdot \delta(x)-\int \delta(x)dx$,
as a result $ x\cdot\delta'(x)=-\delta(x)$, but for the next derivative it doesn't work.
I can't understand when $n$ appears.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Be careful!  You need to do more than just pairing the distribution on the constant function $1$.

We have
\begin{align*}
\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)x\delta'(x)=-\int_\mathbb{R}[f(x)x]'\delta(x)=-f(0)=-\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\delta(x)
\end{align*}
which we can write as
$$
x\delta'+\delta=0.\tag{1}
$$
Assuming(*) you have seen the product rule for differentiating distributions, we have
\begin{align*}
0&=\delta'+x\delta''+\delta'=x\delta''+2\delta'\tag{$1'$}\\
0&=\delta''+x\delta^{(3)}+2\delta''=x\delta^{(3)}+3\delta''\tag{$1''$}\\
0&=\delta^{(3)}+x\delta^{(4)}+3\delta^{(3)}=x\delta^{(4)}+4\delta^{(3)}\tag{$1'''$}\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}

---

(*)If you haven't seen the product rule, you can proceed as follows
\begin{align*}\require{cancel}
\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)x\delta^{(m)}(x)&=-\int_\mathbb{R} [f(x)x]'\delta^{(m-1)}(x)\\
&=\dots\\
&=(-1)^m\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^m}{\mathrm{d}x^m}\right\rvert_{x=0}[f(x)x]\\
&=(-1)^m[\cancel{f^{(m)}(0)\cdot 0}+m f^{(m-1)}(0)]\\
&=-m\cdot(-1)^{m-1}f^{(m-1)}(0)\\
&=-m\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\delta^{(m-1)}(x)
\end{align*}
for all test function $f$.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

**Using Fourier transform**

First recall that
$$
\mathcal{F}\{u'\} = i\xi \, \mathcal{F}\{u\}, \quad
\mathcal{F}\{xu\} = i\frac{d}{d\xi} \mathcal{F}\{u\}, \quad
\mathcal{F}\{\delta\} = 1.
$$

From this follows that
$$
\mathcal{F}\{\delta^{(m)}\} = (i\xi)^m \mathcal{F}\{\delta\} = (i\xi)^m.
$$

Then,
$$
\mathcal{F}\{x\delta^{(m)}\}
= i\frac{d}{d\xi} \mathcal{F}\{\delta^{(m)}\}
= i\frac{d}{d\xi} (i\xi)^m
= i^2 m \, (i\xi)^{m-1}
= -m \, \mathcal{F}\{\delta^{(m-1)}\}.
$$

Thus, since the Fourier transform is bijective,
$$
x\delta^{(m)} = -m \, \delta^{(m-1)}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Using generalized product rule for functions**

We are used to the product rule $(fg)' = f'g + fg'.$ For higher order derivatives this generalizes to
$$
(fg)^{(m)} = \sum_{k=0}^{m} {m \choose k} f^{(k)} g^{(m-k)}.
$$

Applying this to the left hand side of the identity to be shown gives,
$$\begin{align}
\langle x \delta^{(m)}, \varphi \rangle
&= \langle \delta^{(m)}, x \varphi \rangle \\
&= (-1)^m \langle \delta, (x \varphi)^{(m)} \rangle \\
&= (-1)^m \langle \delta, \sum_{k=0}^{m} {m \choose k} x^{(k)} \varphi^{(m-k)} \rangle \\
&= (-1)^m \sum_{k=0}^{m} {m \choose k} \langle \delta, x^{(k)} \varphi^{(m-k)} \rangle \\
&= (-1)^m \sum_{k=0}^{m} {m \choose k} \left. x^{(k)} \varphi^{(m-k)} \right|_{x=0}
\\
&= \{ \text{ only the term for $k=1$ will contribute } \} \\
&= (-1)^m \, m \, \varphi^{(m-1)} \\
&= -m \, (-1)^m\varphi^{(m-1)} \\
&= -m \, \langle \delta^{(m-1)}, \varphi \rangle. \\
\end{align}$$

Since this is valid for any test function $\varphi$ we have $x\delta^{(m)} = -m\delta^{(m-1)}.$

I have above used a common notation for distributions acting on a test function. You can think of $\langle u, \varphi \rangle$ as $\int u(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx.$